# Undefined: revel.TestSuites

Tags: go, revel

I'm having some problems getting [Revel](http://revel.github.io/) up and running after I did an update on the package. Each time I try to run a revel app I get the following error message:

```
Go Compilation Error
The Go code go/src/github.com/revel/samples/booking/app/tmp/main.go does not compile: undefined: revel.TestSuites
```

At first I thought this was due to some legacy code in my current project, but then I tried to get the official sample projects to work, but the same error comes up in these as well. Don't know how to push this further. I don't even use the `testrunner`, so it shouldn't even get generated in the `main.go` file.

*Update*

Looks like I had a old revel binary, had to remove this and get the revel cmd package, after I did this the `TestSuites` problem got solved.

Comment: Sawtan, [so] isn't a forum. Here you don't edit an answer into the question and use tags like '[solved]. Instead, if you have an answer to your own question you simply "Post Your Answer" (see [answer] and [Can I answer my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Revel, but [Godoc tells us](https://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel/testing) that `TestSuites` is now in `github.com/revel/revel/testing` package. The Revel developers might've moved the testing related stuff into a separate package.

Comment: Looks like my revel binary was way old, had to remove it and get the revel cmd package, now it seems to work as per usual! Thanks for the help!